# Generalization of uniq

Tags: uniq

The [`uniq(1)`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/1posix/uniq/) command can be viewed as a tiny [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function))/[reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function))-style program:

- map consecutive, identical input lines into groups;
- reduce the list of lines (which are all identical) to a single line.

Are there more examples of programs in this (functional) style in Unix? And, if I would like to use another map or reduce function, are there more generic tools out there that let one provide custom mappers and reducers?

Maybe something like this:

```
mapreducer -mapper prog1 -reducer prog2 < input > output
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a tool out there called "bashreduce"

Article: 
http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7407/

GitHub:
https://github.com/erikfrey/bashreduce